# Custom List view for a sliding menu

Tags: android, listview, menu, sliding

**EDIT:**Ive got this to work now. Made the necessary changes in the code below.

I am trying to create a slidng menu in and android application. The sliding menu must contain a customized list view with an image and a text view. Although I am able to get the sliding menu, I cannot seem to get any content into the list view.

This is my Main activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Context context=this;
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenu, null, true);



    final ListView lv=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    SlidingMenu menu=new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidth(5);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setBehindWidth(100);
    menu.setMenu(v);
    menu.setOnOpenListener(new OnOpenListener() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            MenuAdapter ma=new MenuAdapter(context);
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
        }
    });


}
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
Context context;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

public MenuAdapter(Context c) {
    super(c, R.layout.menucontent);
    context=c;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /*int height=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int width=LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;*/


    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.menucontent, parent, false);
    TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

    tv.setText("Hello World");

    return view;
}
```

}

P.S: I have 3 different XML files- main.xml which is the launcher activity, slidingmenu.xml which displays the menu and finally menucontent.xml which has the text and image views that should be displayed in the list.

Comment: I don't see where you're putting any items into your MenuAdapter.

Comment: I didnt get you. Ive used the tv.setText() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override, `getCount()` method of `MenuAdapter` to return some value greater than 1 like, 2, 10. Then you will be able to see the list items.

Comment: Its still not working. Actually Ive just realized that the getView() method is not being called at all!

Comment: Actually the getCount() method did get it to work. I've had to make a few changes to the code, which I've updated. Thanks for your help.